# I have Data Models...Now What in Google App Engine With Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I have what I think I need for models in google app engine.  I'm building basically a classifieds ad system.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Cities(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    connectors = db.ListProperty()
    catList = db.ListProperty()



class Listings(db.model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.CategoryProperty()
    city = db.StringProperty()
    editURL = db.LinkProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    phone = db.PhoneNumber()
    user = db.UserProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    content = db.TextProperty()
    picture = db.BlobProperty()
    location = db.StringProperty()
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with those?  Also, I have these in a file called dbmodels.py in the same directory as all my other files for Google App engine.  Is there a way I can import these into the particular files where they'll need to be used?

Lastly, I have a list of cities I want to be represented.  How do I get that into google app engine?  Is the right thing to do is build a dashboard in which I can create my own cities?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is nothing obviously wrong with them
2. In something like `i_use_models.py` have `from dbmodels import Cities, Listings` (assuming they are in the same folder), and use `Cities` and `Listings`
3. It is the right way, but make sure only administrators can edit that. (Or, better, read  Thomas K's comment below)

Comment: on 3, You can do simple admin of the datastore from the app's dashboard, which might be useful in this case. There is also  a way to run bulk uploads of data from the API, although it's not useful if you'll want to edit things later.